# Difficulty on Debugging Race Condition with Pthreads in C for HttpServer

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, threadpool, semaphore, race-condition

I'm building an http server in C using Pthreads and having issue where the program will stop(thinking it's a race condition for this reason) when I send in a curl request.

Here is my main function where the main thread waiting for a request to come to push to the queue.

```
    queue_t *Q = queue_new(5);
    sem_t num_of_requests;
    sem_init(&num_of_requests, 0,0);
    Sem_n_Queue* info = (Sem_n_Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Sem_n_Queue));
    info->semaphore = num_of_requests;
    info->Q = Q;
    pthread_t th[threads];
    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        if(pthread_create(&th[i], NULL,&startThread, (void*)info ) != 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to create thread");
        }
     }  
     while(true)
     {
     int accept_socketfd = accept(socketfd, NULL, NULL);
        Task t = {
            .task_function = &process_request,
            .socket = accept_socketfd,
            .logfile = audit_fd
        };
        queue_push(Q, &t);
        sem_post(&num_of_requests);
     }
```

//My thread pool

```
    void* startThread(void* args)
    {
    Sem_n_Queue* info = (Sem_n_Queue*)args;
    int val;
    sem_getvalue(&info->semaphore, &val);
    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&info->semaphore); 
        Task task;
        queue_pop(info->Q, (void**)&task);
        executeTask(&task);        
    }
    }
```

//Here is my queue push since I notice it gets stuck at the mutex lock

```
    bool queue_push(queue_t *q, void *elem) 
    {
    if (!q) {
        return false;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q->queue_op);
    while (q->counter == q->size) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&q->queue_full, &q->queue_op);
    }

    q->buffer[q->head] = (void *) elem;
    q->head = (q->head + 1) % q->size;
    q->counter += 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->queue_op);
    pthread_cond_signal(&q->queue_empty);
    return true;
    }
```

(Update Including queue pop)
Here is my queue pop

```
    bool queue_pop(queue_t *q, void **elem) {
    if (!q) {
        return false;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q->queue_op);
    while (q->counter == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&q->queue_empty, &q->queue_op);
    }
    *elem = q->buffer[q->tail];
    q->buffer[q->tail] = NULL;
    q->tail = (q->tail + 1) % q->size;
    q->counter -= 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->queue_op);
    pthread_cond_signal(&q->queue_full);
    return true;
    }
```

1st I've tried adding

```
    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        if(pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to join the thread");
        }
    }
```

before and after the main while loop. I thought having pthreads after will ensure the program has to wait for the threads to complete their tasks in an event of a termination on the server. But I noticed that when i do that either the main thread gets stuck at the mutex lock in push or once the main thread pushes and sem_post the pthread at sem_wait() won't actually begin executing the task.

My assumption was pthreads wait at sem_wait so when main thread pushes a task a thread will wake up and begin a task. I've been working with just 1 pthread and using a debugger but I can't seem to spot why these issues happen.

My idea of using a semaphore is that initial value would be zero meaning no task are available so when the pthreads arrive they will have to wait until the main thread sem_post() after queueing a new request.

This is done locally so I have two terminals open. One for running the server and the other for sending in http requests. When I also try to debug I do it this way as well but I can't tell if I"m doing it correctly on debugging when dealing with pthreads and having to wait for a user to send in a request.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. You say that `queue_push` gets stuck waiting for the mutex lock (`q->queue_op` I presume?) But, `queue_op` appears nowhere else in your example. If `queue_push` is stuck waiting for it, then some other thread must have locked it. Where is the code for that other thread? \[P.S., Looks like you're trying to implement a blocking queue. Looks like you're also using a counting semaphore. But if your queue operations block, then why do you need the semaphore at all?]

Comment: Hi Solomon, thank you for the response. I didn't include queue_op as I didn't think it was needed. I can add it. The reason I'm using a semaphore is to prevent a dead lock on the initialization of the pthreads. When I didn't have the semaphores the pthreads would go right into queue pop(ill add this function code) grab a mutex lock but since the queue is empty itll wait. While this is happening the main thread is waiting for a response and when it tries to push to the queue it won't because the pthread has the lock still. The semaphore is more to act as a way to not dequeue on an empty queue

Comment: Are you aware that `pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex)` unlocks the `mutex` while it is waiting, and then locks it again before it returns?

Comment: I was unaware of that. I thought it was a way for the thread to go to "sleep" to not waste cpu usage.

Comment: Update  - removing the semaphore lead to me finding out there was a seg fault which was based on how I was dequeuing since it was a void. Seems to be working. Ty again @SolomonSlow for the help

Comment: FWIW, this line `info->semaphore = num_of_requests;` copies a semaphore, which is not a valid thing to do.

Comment: Thank you so much @EmployedRussian.  I didn't even noticed that. I think that was causing the stalling.

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex)` is a way to for a "consumer" thread to go to "sleep" and not waste waste CPU usage _while it is waiting for some other thread to "produce" something._ It needs the `mutex` because whatever the "something" is, there will be shared variables in the picture, and you need lock the mutex whenever you access shared variables. But, the "producer" thread can't touch those variables if the "consumer" keeps the mutex locked while it is waiting, so that's why `pthread_cond_wait` unlocks the mutex for the duration of the wait.